# Change my where query depend on input text

Tags: php, sql

I want my input text to go in my where query, I can make it work with numbers, but when i try to search with letters in the input field. It doesn't work. Any suggestion? Do i need to convert something ?

```
<form name="form" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <input type="submit" name="button1"  value="Search">
</form>

$nickval = $_GET["test"];
```

This one is working.

```
//Establish connection to database
$host = "****";
$conn = ******
$query = " Select * 
from p900
where p900key = $nickval
ORDER BY P900KEY";
```

This one doesnt work, In input i write AB which is signature.

```
//Establish connection to database
$host = "****";
$conn = ******
$query = " Select * 
from p900
where p900SIG= $nickval
ORDER BY P900key";
```

Sorry if im unclear, i tried my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For letters in where condition you have to wrapped textbox value in quotes like below.

```
//Establish connection to database
$host = "****";
$conn = ******
$query = " Select * 
from p900
where p900SIG= '$nickval'
ORDER BY P900key";
```

Comment: the data coming from textbox is already in string format

Comment: Yes, so to match string value in DB value should be quoted. For numeric value comparison no need of quotes.

Comment: thanks man, much appreciated